# VBA: Update Shape Attributes Based on Excel Table

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have an Excel table full of attributes in columns A:L that are pulled from a PowerPoint file. I am trying to update shapes in my PowerPoint based on the attributes listed in the table (i.e. the Fill color says Red and I change it to Blue in Excel and then hit Go and it updates in PowerPoint). Any idea why this is failing?

I have the following code but it fails on the following line:

```
    For Each oSl In oSlides

Error: Runtime Error '424' Object required
```

```
Sub test()
    Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim newslide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim slideCtr As Integer
    Dim tb As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    Dim oShAttributes As Range
    Dim oSlides As Slides
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
    
    Set oShAttributes = Range("A1:L5")

    Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    PPT.Visible = True
    Set oSlides = PPT.Presentations.Open( _
        "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\vbatest.pptx")
    slideCtr = 1

    For Each oSl In oSlides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            oSh.Name = oShAttributes(i, 2)
            oSh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = oShAttributes(i, 3)
            oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = oShAttributes(i, 4)
            oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = oShAttributes(i, 5)
            oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = oShAttributes(i, 6)
            oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = oShAttributes(i, 7)
            oSh.Left = oShAttributes(i, 9)
            oSh.Top = oShAttributes(i, 10)
            oSh.Width = oShAttributes(i, 11)
            oSh.Height = oShAttributes(i, 12)
            i = i + 1
        Next oSh
    Next oSl
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You never assigned anything to oSlides.

Comment: I adjusted it to oSlides = the Presentation that was opened, but am now getting a type mismatch here.... Is that because it needs to be active?

Comment: oSlides is not the same type as `Presentations.Open(...)` returns. `Presentations.Open(...)` returns a Presentation object. You can use `.Slides` to get the Slides collection for the Presentation.